# Commerce Dynamic Address Field Issue

Tags: commerce, entities

I've got a problem with the dynamic address field. Maybe it is a problem with the feed-importer, not quite sure about that.

I've imported customers to my database, in the view, name and address are displayed correctly but when i click on edit, those fields are empty. Seems like they are correct in the database.

Comment: Make sure that the country is correctly set, addressfield depends on the country to display the structure.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Any chance to save addresses without a country?

Comment: @pcambra Looks like your comment should be upgraded to an answer!

Comment: I think already did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressfield module depends on the country for displaying the right structure of the form that is configured by the plugin, I'm afraid country is mandatory so you can just select one in the field settings so you don't have the selector, then you'll need to do some theming magic for hiding it when it's displayed